# Re-assigning the value to a double in a for loop

Tags: java

I'm currently working on a program that will calculate a simple interest rate and monthly payment taken from a loan. Although, I am running into one pretty big problem. I am trying to make it so that my principal value(see in code) is re-assigned the value of my new balance(see in code). Here is my code right now, I will explain in better detail under it:

```
import java.util.Scanner;


 public class Payments {

public static double principal;       //principal
public static double annualrate;     //annual interest rate
public static double p;             //monthly payment
public static double mr;           //monthly interest rate
public static double nb;          //new balance after monthly payments
public static double i;          //interest (monthly)
public static String spaces = "           "; //spaces for making clean columns
public static int months = 12;

public static void main(String[] args){

    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("Principal: $");
    principal  = input.nextDouble();

    System.out.println("Anual Interest Rate: ");
    annualrate = input.nextDouble();

    System.out.println("Monthly Payment: $");
    p = input.nextDouble();


    calculate();

}

public static void calculate() {
    mr = annualrate / 12;
    i = mr * p;
    nb = principal + i - p;





    System.out.print("Month     Principal Amt.        Interest       Payment         New Balance");
    System.out.println();
    System.out.println();

    for(int x = 1; nb > 0; nb = principal + i - p){

        System.out.println(x + spaces + p + spaces + i + "%" + spaces + "$"           + p + spaces + "$" + nb);
             p = (Double)null;
             p = nb;

         }

     }
 }
```

So as you can most likely see by the comments in the code, all of the variables are shown. Now, disregard the null and me casting it to a double because that was the last thing that I tried to do before asking you guys :)  anyways, my final question is, how can I go about re-assigning the value of principal to my new balance (nb)? Also, a side question, would a while-loop be better for this kind of program?

Comment: Not an answer to your actual question, but: Look at your loop `for(int x = 1; nb > 0; x++){`, the condition is `nb > 0`, but `nb` never changes in the loop. So either the loop get's skipped right away or executes forever...

Comment: okay, that was actually a side question I was going to add but didn't. It does in fact go on forever. So should I change my for-loop to something like: for(int x = 1; nb > 0; nb = principal + i - p)?

Comment: Where do you set principal?

Comment: Yeah, sorry about that! I had a small error since I re-named my principal variable in the middle of writing it to avoid self-confusion. I will edit the post to show that.

Comment: Along with many issues I couldn't help but notice nb = p + i - p;
As in nb = i;

Comment: Oh, yeah. I changed that too. But it did not alter the outcome of anything.

Comment: what happens when you do `p = nb`?

Comment: @Samiam it doesn't do anything. It is useless to have

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has already been said in the comments, but the most immediate problem that I can see is in

```
for(int x = 1; nb > 0; x++){
```

your condition, `nb > 0` will never ever change in that loop.

This means 1 of 2 things

- your loop won't execute
- your loop won't exit (infinite loop)

judging by how you're calculating `nb`(new balance) I'm assuming that it's going to be above 0 most of the time, and that your loop will never stop.

As things are right now, I'm not entirely sure what you actually want to do in that `for` loop or whether you even want a for loop at all, as that part is unclear.

---

what is the `for` loop supposed to do?

it almost looks like you're attempting to do something like

```
for (int x = 1; principal > 0; x++)
{
    principal += principal * monthlyInterestRate;
    principal -= payment;

    System.out.println("insert output here");
}
```

Comment: I changed the for loop to this: for(int x = 1; nb > 0; nb = principal + i - p) and it does an infinite loop where the values change from $500 to $100 (with the beginning inputs at $500 principal, 12% annual rate, and $100/m payments)

Comment: @SullyBrooks are they alternating?

Comment: Yes they are. I am working on cleaning up many of the dumb errors I made right now

Comment: @SullyBrooks `1.` Instead of this `p = (Double)null; p = nb;` use `principal = nb;` `2.` `for(int x = 1; nb > 0; nb = principal + i - p)` instead use `for(int x = 1; nb > 0; nb = principal + i - p,x++)` .  I think these fixes will solve your problem. but not sure

Comment: @SullyBrooks i've edited my answer.  is that what you're trying to do?

Comment: Well almost! I see what you are trying to do, but it still has an infinite loop! I think it is my slopping coding. I'm going to try and clean it up a bit and see if it works! Thanks though

Answer (score 1):

nb = p + i - p; ???? looks like you need to double check your code.. the for loop doesnot change the condition at any place.. if the value is greater than 0, you will always lead it to an infinite loop, or it will never enter the loop at all( if np<1) . so check you code for runtime errors..

Comment: Well yeah, I fixed those small dumb mistakes and the objective of this program is to show the monthly payments for every month and the interest until the balance is < 0. Thats why I put the nb > 0; in the for-loop

Comment: @SullyBrooks But you are not changing `nb` at all.

Comment: Oh, dang it! I uploaded an older version of the code! anyways, I changed the for loop to this: for(int x = 1; nb > 0; nb = principal + i - p) and it does an infinite loop where the values change from $500 to $100 (with the beginning inputs at $500 principal, 12% annual rate, and $100/m payments)